# Cook's D, testing for outliers

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, outliers

I am working on a multiple linear regression and I want to check for outliers using Cook's D. I have a problem interpreting it, as there are many points above the 4/N line, but only one is >1. How should I interpret it? Is only the one case that is >1 problematic or all of them above the estimated line?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen different lines given in different places.  In my own simulations, I have often found points above 4/N by chance alone when nothing is wrong, but that >1 does pick up real outliers.  However, by deleting the outliers greater than some threshold, you run the risk of chasing your tail in the sense that you run the regression with the new (subset) data and then find that some other data point ends up being called an outlier.  There is also a question of the reliability of this process in that another person might reasonably pick a different threshold and get different results.  A better way if you think there may be outliers, is to just run a robust regression from the start.  That is, you would use a different loss function, like Tukey's [bisquare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics#M-estimators) instead of OLS, to fit your model.

Comment: To run a robust regression would be a good option, but I am supposed to use a multiple linear regression and check for outliers. I also used an added-variable-plot which showed pretty much the same results - many deviating points for the tree independent variables that I used for the model.

Comment: Who says you are "supposed" to do this?

Comment: it`s predefined in the details for the university project, I am working on.

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class?

Comment: yes, so I can`t use other regression model

Comment: Please read our [policies](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for classwork questions.